# Convert a dictionary of list to a dataframe in a specific format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary with each key holding a list of values. Now, I want to convert that to an dataframe in a specific format.

Example -

```
dct = {key1:["North", "South", "East"], key2:["East"], key3:["East", "West", "North", "South"]}

The table should look like

key1   North
       South
       East
key2   East
key3   East
       West
       North
       South
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `DataFrame` in list comprehension for tuples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, x) for k, v in dct.items() for x in v], columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
      a      b
0  key1  North
1  key1  South
2  key1   East
3  key2   East
4  key3   East
5  key3   West
6  key3  North
7  key3  South
```

In pandas for need replace non existing values by `NaN` or some another value, like here `''` for empty string:

```
#replace values by NaN
#df['a'] = df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated())

df['a'] = df['a'].mask(df['a'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
      a      b
0  key1  North
1        South
2         East
3  key2   East
4  key3   East
5         West
6        North
7        South
```

If need convert `a` column to index (but stil index values are `key1, key2, key3 and ''`):

```
s = df.set_index('a')['b']
print (s)
a
key1    North
        South
         East
key2     East
key3     East
         West
        North
        South
Name: b, dtype: object
```